# No author_id found

Tags: django, django-models

so basically I'm getting

> DatabaseError at /admin/coltrane/entry/
>
> no such column: coltrane_entry.author_id

this and have no idea how to fix it.

> author = models.ForeignKey(User)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've added this column after adding the table to the database.

So, to fix it you have 2 options.

1. Remove the table and run `manage.py syncdb` again
2. Use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) and migrate the table changes

Comment: I've installed South, however it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Marijus: Just installing South isn't enough, you have to make sure that the South state is identical to your database state, after that you can make your modifications, create a migration and apply the migration. South won't automatically fix all your problems for you, but it's a way of fixing them.